# Inject a resolve provider from child state to controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

So i'm trying to pull some `id` from the url parameters.

**Here are my states :**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        url: '/parent',
            templateUrl: 'path/to/parent.html',
            controller: 'lolController'
        })
    .state('parent.child', {
        url: '/child-profile/:id',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/child.html',
        resolve: {
            someId: function  ($stateParams) {
                // I cant print the id from here
                console.log("PARAMS", $stateParams.id)
                return $stateParams.id;
            }
          },
    })
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('lolController', 
    ['$scope', 'someId', function ($scope, someId) {

     $scope.someId = someId;

}])
```

But whenever i'm trying to access the url `/parent/child-profile/123abc` i'm getting the error `Unknown provider: someId` [See error here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=studentIdProvider).

How do I fix this? Thanks.

**EDIT**

The answer provided by [Jay Shukla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1502868/jay-shukla) helped me get this idea.

The `parameter` is `undefined` because I declared the controller on the parent state before actually calling the child state which contains the value from it's url. Here's a simple solution I came up with, with Jay Shukla's help.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        url: '/parent',
            templateUrl: 'path/to/parent.html',
        })
    .state('parent.child', {
        url: '/child-profile/:id',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/child.html',
        controller: 'lolController'
    })
```

I removed the `controller` declaration from the parent state and moved it to the child state. Since in my situation the parent state's template only contains a `<div ui-view></div>`.

The idea is :

> Only state is nested but both html are separate so controller models will not be inherited - Jay Shukla

Each state can have their own controller.

Please add/edit more to improve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to inject `$stateParams` then you will get id in that object.

Like this

```
.controller('lolController', 
    ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams) {

     $scope.someId = $stateParams.id;

}])
```

You can also defined your parameters in different ways as below

```
url: '/child-profile/:id', // Inside stateparams you will get id as key
OR
url: '/child-profile/{id}',
OR
url: '/child-profile/:{id:int}', // Id with integer value
```

Comment: It says undefined. :(

Comment: I tried all 3 ways, all are `undefined`. :/ By the way Im accessing the url `/parent/child-profile/5ampl3`

Comment: try removing resolve function from your stateProvider. You don't need that

Comment: I think the problem is that the child state can't access the controller. Maybe there's a way to do that? Coz if I declare a separate controller for the child state, the parameter has a value.

Comment: Your url will be like this url: 'parent/child-profile/:id',

Comment: I found a way. I tried to remove the `controller` declaration from the parent state and put it on the child state instead since im not doing anything in the `controller` from the parent state. What do you think?

Comment: Yes. that will work. Anyway you have to define any controller for child.html otherwise you won't get that values. Only state is nested but both html are separate so controller models will not be inherited.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. Thanks. I will edit my question to explain the problem further more. Your answer helped me a lot.